# Internal Server Error with scrapy when run from script on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, pythonanywhere

I'm faced with kind of a weird issue regarding a scrapy spider on pythonanywhere.

I'm running a few of these spiders. I start them by calling python scripts via scheduled tasks checking whether an instance of the spider is already running and if not, running the spider. The scripts look like this:

```
from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance()

import os
class cd:
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = os.path.expanduser(newPath)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)


from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

with cd("/home/username/notebooksbilliger"):
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl('notebooksbilliger')
    process.start()
```

With most spiders this script works just fine, but with one particular spider, while the spider starts, it always throws 500 Internal Server Errors like the following, which cause the spider to abort:

```
2015-09-03 14:07:19 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/handys+smartphones/> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-09-03 14:08:13 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-09-03 14:08:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/handys+smartphones/> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-09-03 14:09:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/handys+smartphones/> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2015-09-03 14:09:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/handys+smartphones/> (referer: None)
2015-09-03 14:09:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <500 http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/handys+smartphones/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2015-09-03 14:09:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

If I run the spider by simply calling "scrapy crawl notebooksbilliger" in the shell, everything works just fine.

Does anyone have a clue why this might be happening or could point me to a way how to find out why this is happening?

Comment: Are you perhaps somehow running your scheduled task in a different version of Python or with a different version of scrapy?

Comment: I checked and both times it's Python 2.7.6 and Scrapy 1.0.3

Comment: It's interesting that it's giving you an internal server error.  That's something that I'd only expect to see if it was coming from the server you're accessing.  Are you sure it's *exactly* the same data that you're sending when you run it from the shell as it is when you run it from a scheduled task?  I'm imagining that if you were sending slightly different data, the site might respond to an error for one kind of data and not for another

Comment: I think I might have found an explanation. It appears that you get assigned different IP addresses most times you start a new Bash console on pythonanywhere, while the IP addresses for the scheduled tasks are mostly (or always?) the same. So maybe the IP address assigned to my scheduled tasks was blocked by the site and throwing internal server errors is their way of stopping people from scraping it. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: That could be it.  It would be a bit odd for the other server to respond with a 500 (Internal server error) message when it's blocking an IP -- I'd expect a 403 (Forbidden) or something -- but it's certainly not impossible.  Perhaps there's a bug in their IP blocking code ;-)